# Quick way to remove solidify thickness

Tags: modifiers

I have made the mesh and added solidify modifier and applied. But later i thought to increase the thickness. So now i want to remove thickness so that i can added the solidify modifier again. I want to know is there any quick remove thicknes. When i select the edge then ctrl+ the selection goes downward not to single face. So i want to know a quick way to decrease thickness. Any suggestion or help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why did you need to apply the modifier?

Comment: I had the same problem. Then i used "C" to select all external faces, so with all of them selected I press "Ctrl+i" to invert selection. so All of the internal faces could be deleted faster than i could imagine :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to manually select the edge loops around the boundary, still using the alt-click to select them in vertex select mode until they are all selected.[image: vertex select] Then you will need to change to face select mode, and delete the faces.[image: face select][image: faces deleted] Then you will need to select a face on the surface you want to delete [image: single face selected] and press L to select all linked faces [image: full selection] and then delete them, leaving your original surface ready for editing.[image: final surface]

Comment: You don't need to "manually" select the faces joining each side. In face select mode you can Alt-Click next to a small edge between two sides to select all the faces around the mesh, in vertex select mode Ctrl-Alt-Click does the same. Repeat that for the hole that also joins both sides. Then use Select Linked.

Comment: Except that doesn't take into account ngons and extra geo that doesn't allow for automatic selection - my example is simple but the solution is for anything complicated imho.

Comment: Given that he applied the solidify and wants to undo it, I wouldn't expect any quads or tris along the edge.

Comment: "still using the alt-click to select them in vertex select mode until they are all selected" is what follows the instruction to manually select them - this is the same as what you are saying, no? And this is as generic as possible to apply to the errant searcher for the same kind of solution with possibly not the same mesh scenario (booltool, hardops, etc).

Comment: Well just suggesting that Ctrl-Alt Click should select them all in one go, while in face select mode Alt-Click should too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **just** applied the modifier, use Ctrl Z and cancel it with the "×" button.   Use **Ctrl- F > Solidify** instead as  you can readjust the thickness as many times as you want before you okay it.

Comment: Using Ctrl+F will destructively change the mesh and changes won't be undoable after operator options go from the Last Operator panel. Modifier at least allows for non-desctructive workflow (if not applied).

Comment: @Mr Zak But it **can** be undone when they're there. So... Sometimes you don't want to do complex things using modifiers and **Ctrl + a letter** is enough.

Comment: Yep, it can. Pretty much like any modifier.