# How to get rid of an already applied solidify modifer

Tags: modeling

When starting scuplting I accidentally applied the solidify modifer to my mesh, apart from creating unnessecary geometry it also caused problems with inner vertices sticking out of the mesh.Is there a way to remove the inner layers of vertices ?[image]

[image]

Comment: Not that easy. What you can try is to delete face loops in rims (around openings, e.g. one on the second screenshot) and then you will be able to select one vertex of inner ones and select linked to it geometry with Ctrl+L

Comment: Thanks so much, I wouldn't have expected such an easy way ^^

Comment: Sorry @MrZak - just noticed your comment after posting my inferior answer - you beat me to it. Yours is simpler!

Comment: @RichSedman there's nothing to be sorry for, I was sure there's somewhere question like this one and didn't write the answer to not spend time on that

Comment: Found it - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81583/quick-way-to-remove-solidify-thickness

Answer (score 1):

Providing the inner and outer surfaces are not connected you can select one of the vertices on the inner surface and use the Select/Grow option (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad +</kbd>) to grow that selection to include the whole of the inner surface and then delete (<kbd>X</kbd>).

In your example you'll need to manually select and delete vertices along the edge where the inner connects to the outer first.