# Double faces on UV map?

Tags: modeling, uv, uv-image-editor

I added seams to a cylinder that had a solidify applied to it, the inside is fine and is all connected on the UV map as it should be with the seams  I added but on the outside the majority are messed up with a bunch of duplicates that I can't delete.

If I do remove doubles it doesn't remove any verts and if I move the face either on the 3d view or the map it moves the same face with the same verts and edges connected? I've never seen anything like this...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If possible upload the file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and include link in the question or in comments. Usually if islands in the UV map are split to multiple small ones then there's something with the mesh. Removing doubles might not help due to many reasons, like too low threshold, too high threshold or something alike

Comment: download file is at the bottom, thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't tell how was that done but there are [overlapping faces in the mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfy6S.gif) which cause z-fighting, broken face loops and non-contigous uv map. Removing doubles won't work as expected due to small distance between faces to delete and faces to leave. I'd suggest removing those overlappings maybe even manually. One more flexible approach is removing solidified geometry and using Remove doubles

Comment: How do I go about removing the double manually? removing the face seems to delete "both"?

Comment: It doesn't delete both, that's what is shown in the gif. There are some faces which are not overlapping though. To remove solidify see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81583/quick-way-to-remove-solidify-thickness

Comment: I deleted the entire thing and remade it with extruding instead. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Smart UV Project works for me on 2.79. I added a primitive cylinder Edit/Face mode/deleted the cylinder top face. Back to Object mode/added "Solidify Modifier" (BTW hate that name), applied "Solidify Modifier". Back to edit/face mode, select all/apply Smart UV Project at default settings. Result is fine.

So are you saying that the faces/verts of the outside of the cylinder are locked to the inside faces/verts?

Comment: I'm not using the smart project, I'm manually unwrapping. and as far as I can tell on the model it all looks good, just looks like some faced are duplicated but they aren't...