# Decrease thickness of object

Tags: objects

The following object, in obj format, is 1.6 mm thick and I want it to be 0.8 mm thick.  How do I decrease its thickness (from the inside, so that the outward appearance is still the same)?  When I go to Add Modifier->Solidify, it only allows me to increase the thickness, but not decrease it.

Note:  The suggested previous question does not help me much because I have thousands of faces along the edge to delete when in Edit mode (the original file was obj).
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quick way to remove solidify thickness](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81583/quick-way-to-remove-solidify-thickness)

Comment: please show the object in edit mode to get the topology...

Comment: and / or provide a [sample file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)  I have a bmesh script, that will need reworking if there are tris in the thickness.

Answer (score 2):

Decrease thickness of object

I have made a half sphere and added some solidify modifier and applied to it. To decrease thickness or shrink down the thickness. In edit mode -> select all and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or Mesh -> Transform -> Shrink Fatten

[image]

As soon as u click on or better press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> like we scale we get a arrow to increase or decrease the thickness. After click u can press <kbd>F6</kbd> for operator panel or adjustments. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to flip normal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could simply select (eg) the internal shell, place the 3d cursor at center, select the pivot method for transforms to "3d cursor" and scale the selection:

[image]

here I scaled towards the sphere center

[image]

and here the opposite

[image]

You can't "snap" the scaling to the "middle" of the current thickness, but you can try to determine the needed scaling somehow: eg, try to scale it by increments (or using vertex snapping tools) until the inner shell matches exactly the outer one, note the scaling factor, and then undo, and scale again using a desired percentage (eg 50% of that to go from 1.6 to 0.8).

here I snapped the scaling to a vertex of the outer shell,

[image]

note the scaling in the bottom header: half of that amount, entered by keyboard while scaling, will do the job.